# Uncertainty in connection to explainability

Tags: accuracy, explainable-ai

When I write "uncertainty" in this post I mean:

If I have a classifier into $a_1,..,a_n$ categories and for an observation $x$ I classify $x$ to $a_i$ with probability $p_i$, then the uncertainty of this decision is $1-p_i$.

I'd like to inquire about connections of this notion and that of accuracy and explainability.

For example, if I have a classifier that is "very certain" (on mean/median on the test/training set) how often is this property correlated to achieving real-time accurate predictions? What about vice-versa?

Moreover, if my classifier is "certain" how does this affect my ability to explain its decision in any sense?

I couldn't find good resources for this notion of uncertainty and these questions so I will really appreciate some references as well!

Comment: I assume you meant $1-p_i$ instead of $1-a_i$, right?

Comment: @Erwan yup thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of confusion, I'm afraid:

- The definition you propose for uncertainty doesn't really represent the concept of uncertainty: if $p_i$ is the probability that $x$ belongs to category $a_i$, then $1-p_i$ is just the probability that $x$ *doesn't belong* to category $a_i$.
- Yes, if the classifier assigns a very high $p_i$, say 0.99, it is supposed to mean that the classifier is very confident in its prediction. But it's also the case for a very low probability: if $p_i=0.01$, the classifier is very confident that $x$ doesn't belong to $a_i$. According to your definition, the uncertainty in this case would be very high (0.99) even though the classifier is very confident, so your definition is inconsistent.

Now the main problem: whatever you call a confidence measure based on the probability predicted by the classifier, **it's not reliable**. A prediction is at best an informed decision of the classifier given the data it has seen in the training set and the features of instance. But it could be a random classifier, or a majority-class classifier: in these cases the probability it "predicts" is arbitrary. Imagine you are a teacher and one of your students says "the answer of x=2+2 is x=5", I'm 100% sure". The fact that the student is "100% sure" doesn't make them right, same thing for the classifier. In other words, any reliable measure of uncertainty involves the gold-standard answer, so it's usually part of the evaluation process. That's not to say that the predicted probability is useless, but in general **it has no direct link to accuracy**, and it would be a mistake to interpret it in this way.

Interpretability (or explainability) is a completely different matter: the general idea is to know whether the answer predicted by a classifier can be understood by a human. Typically traditional models like Naive Bayes or Decision Tree models are more directly interpretable (at least with not too many features) than deep NN models.

Comment: Hey your comment regarding the definition is helpful and you're correct. I mean that a decision is not confident, or uncertain, when the classifier makes it based on probability closer to 50% (or some other threshold). Regarding the next point, the link to accuracy, I tend to agree with your position and in fact is why I posted here. Are you aware of any papers that back this intuition? Lastly, regarding the interpretability - also can you think of any references that discuss these two topics together?

Comment: @Mariah I would be surprised that there's any paper studying the link between a predicted probability and accuracy, because it's kind of a given that there is no such link in general. However there are certainly a lot of specific studies which evaluate the performance of a system wrt the probabilities it provides. This reminds me of quality estimation (QE), i.e. the task of predicting the quality/performance of a system (not sure if that's what you're looking for). I'm aware at least of QE for Machine Translation, there might be other QE tasks as well.

Comment: About interpretability I'm really not expert so I can't really help you with that, but afaik it's not related to the question of reliabiity/performance.